# Java split regex patten letters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

I want to split this regexp pattern `2 numbers-3 numbers-5 numbers and letter` in two part. Numbers and "-" one array and the letters in the second array.

I been trying to figure it out for a while. Hoping I can get some help.

Here is an example

```
"12-123-12345A"    <----- the string 
// I want to split it such that it can be ["12-123-12345","A"]
```

I tried this

```
"\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{5}" 
// that only give me ["", "A"]
```

and this

```
"(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"
// ["12", "-", "123", "-", "12345", "A"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\D` matches any non-digit character (including `-`). You'd better to use `[^-\d]` instead to exclude `-`.

```
String s = "12-123-12345A";
String parts[] = s.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[^-\\d])");
System.out.println(parts[0]); // 12-123-12345
System.out.println(parts[1]); // A
```

See a demo: http://ideone.com/emr1Kq

Comment: That work really well but I was wondering if i can restrict the format ?  so `"12-123-123A"` will not  make the split and just return an empty array.

Comment: @AirWick219, It seem like `Matcher.find` is more appropriate for you. See this: http://ideone.com/fsmvnE

Comment: Matcher would be great but split also is accounting for `"12-123-12345"` without the letter in this case I want it to return just ["12-123-12345"]

Comment: Thank you so much... Learned alot.. so i am guess "?" means optional. how about if the end letter is not just one but it can add on...`"12-123-12345A"` or `"12-123-12345AA"` or `"12-123-12345Aaaaaa"`. like split letters and "-" to be group(1) and all the letters to be in group(2)

Comment: @AirWick219, Yes it is. It matches zero or one match of preceding part => optional

Comment: how about if the end letter is not just one but it can add on...`"12-123-12345A"` or `"12-123-12345AA"` or `"12-123-12345Aaaaaa or more letters"`. like split letters and "-" to be group(1) and all the letters to be in group(2)

Comment: @AirWick219, Use `*` (0 or more) or `+` (1 or more) instead of `?`. BTW, please post a separated question if you have more question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String[] a = "12-123-12345A".split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\p{Alpha})");
```

Answer (score 0):

**(\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{5})(\w)**

You can test it on this website

http://regexpal.com/

Here's the java code.  note double slash in replace of slash \ --> \\

```
package com.company;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061614
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{5})(\\w)");
      Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("12-123-12345A");
      matcher.find();
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
      System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    // write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I initially got a match for "^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{5}" but i guess in java it's different ??

Comment: @AirWick219  Guess in java you need to make single slash into double slash.  I added the code above